# Auto genrate a value for a model Field form another Django app model field

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

```
//App ITEMS APP(1)

class ItemsDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    sellPrice = models.FloatField()
    costPrice = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

//App ORDERS (APP 2)

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        ItemsDetail,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field='name',
        blank=True,
    )

    price = models.FloatField()
```

Now when user selects `Order.item` form a drop down list in admin interface, I want `Order.price` to have a value of `ItemsDetail.sellPrice`

[admin interface of Orders. Want to generate value for price according to item selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSq3o.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have few choices.

First and simple choice - just change `__str__` in your model.

Like this.

```
class ItemsDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    sellPrice = models.FloatField()
    costPrice = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sellPrice
```

But you can't use this approch if you want `__str__` for other field.

Second, you can override `formfield_for_foreignkey` itself.

```
class ItemsChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "Item: {}".format(obj.name)


class YourOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'item':
            return ItemsChoiceField(queryset=ItemsDetail.objects.all())
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

For more detail, check [`django admin cookbook`](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/fk_display.html)

Comment: I want to get sellPrice value upon selecting a value from item field and then want to display in price field ?

Comment: I don't understand well.. What exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to override the django admin template, you do by creating admin folder inside template the model name folder in side that you can create change_form.html. Iside that you have to write the javascript code on value change

```
{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.add-another').click(function(e) {
                //set the value manually.
        });
    })(django.jQuery);
</script>
```

{% endblock %}